# Using gwt widgets in errai ui

Tags: gwt, uibinder, errai

I would like to know if it is possible to use complex gwt widgets like MenuBar or TabLayoutPanel in errai ui.

For example, how can I port the following uibinder to errai's ui template?

```
<g:MenuBar ui:field="menuBar">
    <g:MenuItem ui:field="helpMenuItem">Help</g:MenuItem>
    <g:MenuItem ui:field="aboutMenuItem">About</g:MenuItem>
    <g:MenuItem ui:field="siteMapMenuItem">Site Map</g:MenuItem>
</g:MenuBar>
```

I think I could use a `<div>` in the template, and bind it to a MenuBar, but I would have to construct the menu items programmatically in the view, which I want to avoid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct the menu and its items programmatically if you want to stick only with Errai UI.
However you could put the menu in a separate widget which could be built with UI-Binder.

GWT's UI-Binder can represent Widgets as well as DOM elements whereas Errai UI only works with a DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what you say is true.. I ended up using a mixed approach, erraiui and programming widgets when needed (for example celltable). I also asked this question in errai forum and got this answer https://developer.jboss.org/thread/249243